# Most efficient way to get the total count of a query, but only retrieving the first N items

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I'm working on a **custom** pagination on a laravel query. I am not using laravel own `paginate()` because it doesn't suit my situation.

Basically something like this:

```php
$items = MyModel::where('field', 'stuff')
   ->where('some other complex subquery')
   ->limit($limit)
   ->offset($offset)
   ->get();
```

The query works perfectly, but I also need to return the total number of items available to better display the pagination on the client.

One option i have is to clone the query and perform a separated `count` query, something like this:

```php
$query = MyModel::where('field', 'stuff')
   ->where('some other complex subquery');

$totalCount = (clone $query)->count();

$items = $query->limit($limit)
   ->offset($offset)
   ->get();
```

the problem is, I have to perform two queries. I have several conditions on nested relationships and the query is not really lightweight, so I don't like the idea of doubling it.

Considering laravel itself need to do it inside its own `paginate()` method, are there some more efficient ways to perform this?

Comment: There used to be [FOUND_ROWS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows), but it will be phased out in favor of two queries. Then there's also the option of a temporary table: You put all results in that, and then use the LIMIT on it.

Comment: Not really. even if you see only one methode `paginate`, eloquent is doing two queries. besides that, count queries are way faster than select ones.